# validate input is a number, in a range of numbers or a specific character

Tags: java, validation, input

I have written the following code that checks if an input value is a number or the character 'R' or 'r'.

I also need to check that if it is a number, it is greater than 0 and less than an array length.

Is it possible to do all of this on same line as the existing conditions?

```
int array_length = menu.length;
while (!input.hasNextInt() && !input.hasNext("[rR]")) {
    System.out.println("Invalid option entered. Please try again.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Select option > ");
    input.next();
}
```

Comment: sure, wouldn't make it very readable/maintainable though

Comment: How can I get the value of the input in the condition?

Comment: @AsaCarter Declare an integer before the loop (i.e. `int inputNumber;`), then assign it inside the condition: `(inputNumber = input.nextInt()) <= 0`. But, as Stultuske said, this would make the code not so readable/maintainable. If you want the condition to take just a line, consider writing a method which checks the input and returns `true` if the input is ok or `false` if it's not, then call it inside the `while` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not optimizing string comparison here, but basically that's what you probably need.

```
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int array_length = 5;

    String value;
    while (!"R".equals(value = input.next()) &&
            !"r".equals(value) &&
            !(value.matches("[0-9]+") && Integer.parseInt(value) >= 0 && Integer.parseInt(value) < array_length )) {
        System.out.println("Invalid option entered. Please try again.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Select option > ");
    }

    System.out.println("Thanks!");
```

Comment: The OP asked to also read the input inside the same condition. Also, you do `Integer.parseInt(value)` without checking if the input is really an integer, which will raise a `NumberFormatException` if there is no integer to parse.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I added the proper validation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to use regular expression for your case.

```
        int size = 3;   // replace by your menu length
        String input = "r";

        String regEx = String.format("^(r|R|[1-9][0-9]*{1,%d}$)", size);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regEx, Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            // your logic here
            // if it comes to this point, it means
            // the input is a number or
            // the input is r or
            // the input is R and
            // the input must be greater than 0
            // the input must be in range is 'size'

            System.out.println("Qualified with all above criteria");
        }
```